# Why I can not insert <object / > tag into CKEditor4?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I have a button in my web page that trigger this function to to insert a video, here is the code:

```
function setVideo(encodeUrl) {
    var url = decodeURIComponent(encodeUrl);
    var htmlstr = "<div id='video_segment'><object  id='obx' name='obx'   width='290' height='260'>";
    htmlstr += "<param name='movie' value='" + url + "'></param>";
    htmlstr += "<param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'></param>";
    htmlstr += "<param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'></param>";
    htmlstr += "<param name='wmode' value='opaque'></param>";
    htmlstr += "<embed src='" + url + "' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' wmode='opaque' width='290' height='260'></embed>";
    htmlstr += "</object></div>";
    alert(htmlstr);
    CKEDITOR.instances.Content.insertHtml(htmlstr);
 }
```

But,it can not insert the object tag into my CKEditor.By the way, I can insert an image by this way. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to configure the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) which is most likely stripping most of that HTML. For example you can extend existing settings with:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'div[id]; object[id,name,width,height]; param[name,value]; ' +
    'embed[src,type,allowscriptaccess,allowfullscreen,wmode,width,height]';
```

Note that there's an official [flash](http://ckeditor.com/addon/flash) plugin, which isn't included in standard CKEditor package (which I guess you have), which would allow by itself all `object`, `embed` and `param` tags.

So if you'll include that plugin in your package, you will be able to omit most of the `extraAllowedContent` which I defined above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I add the flash plugin into my ckeditor ,everything works fine.